# Google Cloud Endpoints: Authentication issues (error 403)

Tags: python, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to connect to my Google Cloud Endpoints API that is running as an Appengine app:

```
@endpoints.api(name='helloworldendpoints', allowed_client_ids=["1234", "12345"], version='v1', auth_level=endpoints.AUTH_LEVEL.REQUIRED)
class HelloWorldApi(remote.Service):
...
```

The API request is as follows:

```
scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"]
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("CloudEndpointsClient.json", scopes)

from httplib2 import Http
http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())

from apiclient.discovery import build

api_root = 'https://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/api'
api = 'helloworldendpoints'
version = 'v1'
discovery_url = '%s/discovery/v1/apis/%s/%s/rest' % (api_root, api, version)
service = build(api, version, discoveryServiceUrl=discovery_url)


response = service.myFunction(myparameter = "123456").execute(http=http_auth)#
print response
```

The requests work well if I remove authentication requirements.
I know that authentication works since the error changes if after authenticating.

The error message I'm getting is:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://my-app.appspot.com/_ah/api/helloworldendpoints/v1/obtainScoreFromEmail?myparameter=1234&alt=json returned "Access Not Configured.  has not been used in project 123456789 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/helloworldendpoints/overview?project=123456789 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.">

I cannot enable the API in my Google Cloud Project, since the API does not exist.

Comment: when you know that the project does not exist, why are you not creating one?

Comment: The project does exist. What's not there is the API service to enable.

Comment: Ok, so in the "Google Console > Library", you can go ahead and enable the api that you intend to use. Which particular api are you not able to find

Comment: The problem here is that it's a custom Cloud Endpoints API called helloworldendpoints which is not available in the library.

Answer (score 0):

What I found to work is a hack around. I used a user authentication (instead of server) on the same project for the same API which worked (https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/access_from_python).

After I switched back to my initial server auth. method it started working.